# Why does it said undefine

Tags: python-3.x, list

What I wrote

if membership_card in [123456, 5678901, 234567, 345678, 456789, 901234]:
print('Your membership card number have been confirm \nWith this you will have 10% discount for your every '
'purchased')
print('Ok, then here are the menu\n' + menu)
order = input('What do you like to order?\n')
Quantity = input("How many would you like?\n")
good_to_go = True
while not good_to_go:
if order == 'Americano':
price = 4
good_to_go = True

```
        elif order == 'Latte':
            price = 7
            good_to_go = True
            whipping_cream_good_to_go = False

            while not whipping_cream_good_to_go:
                add_on = input('Do u want whipping cream\n')
                if add_on == 'Yes':
                    price = 11
                    whipping_cream_good_to_go = True
                if not whipping_cream_good_to_go:
                    print('Invalid syntax')
        elif order == 'Cappuccino':
            price = 9
            good_to_go = True

        elif order == 'Espresso':
            price = 10
            good_to_go = True

        elif order == 'Black Coffe':
            price = 3
            good_to_go = True

    total = price * int(Quantity)
    print('and the total of it is\n' + str(total))
```

What i Got

```
total = price * int(Quantity)
        ^^^^^
```

NameError: name 'price' is not defined. Did you mean: 'print'?

a solution to my python problem

Answer (score 0):

It seems you didn't give price the initial value , and in the process price didn't get any value so at the end it is `undefined`.

Above all the `elif`s and `if`s just give the price a value and the error you just got won't appear again.

Comment: Then how do need to do to solve it cause i have try various idea but none work @Hosseinreza

Comment: @TheCrazyDudeReally can you share all the code?

Comment: if order == 'Americano':
                price = 4
                good_to_go = True

            elif order == 'Latte':
                price = 7
                good_to_go = True
                whipping_cream_good_to_go = False

Comment: while not whipping_cream_good_to_go:
                    add_on = input('Do u want whipping cream\n')
                    if add_on == 'Yes':
                        price = 11
                        whipping_cream_good_to_go = True
                    if not whipping_cream_good_to_go:
                        print('Invalid syntax')
            elif order == 'Cappuccino':
                price = 9
                good_to_go = True

Comment: elif order == 'Espresso':
                price = 10
                good_to_go = True

            elif order == 'Black Coffe':
                price = 3
                good_to_go = True

        total = price * int(Quantity)
        print('and the total of it is\n' + str(total))

Comment: else:
        print("Your membership card is not in the system")
        retype_membership_card_number = input('Please retype your membership card\n')
        if retype_membership_card_number in [123456, 5678901, 234567, 345678, 456789, 901234]:
            print('Your number have been confirmed')
            print('Ok, then here are the menu\n' + menu)
            order = input('What do you like to order?\n')
            good_to_go = True
            while not good_to_go:

Comment: if order == 'Americano':
                    price = 4
                    good_to_go = True

                elif order == 'Latte':
                    price = 7
                    good_to_go = True
                    whipping_cream_good_to_go = False

Comment: while not whipping_cream_good_to_go:
                        add_on = input('Do u want whipping cream\n')
                        if add_on == 'Yes':
                            price = 11
                            whipping_cream_good_to_go = True
                        if not whipping_cream_good_to_go:
                            print('Invalid syntax')
                elif order == 'Cappuccino':
                    price = 9
                    good_to_go = True

Comment: elif order == 'Espresso':
                    price = 10
                    good_to_go = True

                elif order == 'Black Coffe':
                    price = 3
                    good_to_go = True
        else:
            print('Invalid Syntax')
            exit()

Comment: else:
    print('Ok, then here are the menu\n' + menu)
    order = input('What do you like to order?\n')
    ready = True
    while not ready:
        if order == 'Americano':
            price = 4
            ready = True

        elif order == 'Latte':
            price = 7
            ready = True
            whipping_cream_add_on = False

Comment: while not whipping_cream_add_on:
                add_on = input('Do u want whipping cream\n')
                if add_on == 'Yes':
                    price = 11
                    whipping_cream_add_on = True
                if not whipping_cream_add_on:
                    print('Invalid syntax')

Comment: elif order == 'Cappuccino':
            price = 9
            ready = True

        elif order == 'Espresso':
            price = 10
            ready = True

        elif order == 'Black Coffe':
            price = 3
            ready = True